# Pixel perfect collision?

Tags: iphone, pixel-perfect

Is it possible to do pixel perfect collision in a view based application ?  I've been looking for example codes but with no luck... Also can you use colored bitmaps to represent collision for a certain color ?

Answer (score 2):

You can. It looks like it's easiest if you use a **CGImage** though.

You could create a 2D boolean array to read the pixel values to construct a hit grid (basically a 2x2 matrix) and then store that with your game object class.

You would need direct access to the pixel data for the CGImage [(the code is here)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html) then use a for loop, reading the pixel data into the array boolean values:

```
BOOL pixelGrid[xPixels][yPixels];
for (int i = 0; i < xPixels; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < yPixels; j++) {
        pixelGrid[i][j] = pixelIsOpaque(i, j);
    }
}
```

The method pixelIsOpaque() above, obviously doesn't exist, just replace with whatever the sample code gives you to extract the pixel value. You are storing whether a pixel exists (basically check if the pixel is opacity > 0)

Once you have this grid (generate it at the beginning of your program once and store the resultant 2D array inside the game object) then you need a collision detection method.

```
BOOL detectCollision( BOOL *pixelGrid1, BOOL *pixelGrid2 ) {
BOOL result = NO;  
    for (int i = 0; i < xPixels; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < yPixels; j++) {
            if ( pixelGrid1[i][j].opacity != 0 && pixelGrid2[i][j].opacity != 0] ) {
                result = YES; break;
            }

    }
}
return result;
}
```

I just wrote this code on the fly so i may not be 100% compilable but i hope it gives you the idea.
You could easily modify this but instead of comparing against opacity, simply compare against pixel colour value again, [see here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html) for getting the raw colour data.

Comment: +1 for excellent info. I was really interested in pixel perfect collisions myself. I'm gonna try to see if this works this weekend. I'm just concerned about performance, but that's a whole other issue that can be tackled at a later time.